# rm binary in Windows $PATH but Powershell still prefers Remove-Item

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the GNU core utils installed on Windows and have added the `bin` folder to my user `PATH` variable in Windows.

I have found that Powershell prefers Windows native commands over commands with the same name in `PATH`.

For example, when running `get-command rm`, powershell informs me that it's mapped to the internal

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           rm -> Remove-Item
```

Same with any commands where there is a Windows version - `find`, `mkdir`, etc.

Checking commands that I know Windows does not have an alternative for gives me the correct binay location

```
get-command md5sum

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     md5sum.exe                                         5.3.0.1936 C:\Users\alshd\bin\coreutils\bin\md5sum.exe
```

Is there a way to tell PowerShell to prefer the versions I have specified in my PATH over the native Windows commands (without manually aliasing them)?

Comment: you need to EITHER remove the aliases OR use the full name of the command. `mkdir` will give the alias, but `mkdir.exe` will give the utility file.

Comment: How do I remove the built in alias?

Comment: [1] ReadTheFriendlyManual >>> `Get-Help about_Aliases` [*grin*] ///// [2] **_don't remove the aliases ... use the proper names of the external files._** it will be more reliable AND somewhat faster.

Comment: Sadly I have to keep in mind the portability of my scripts. I can't have `rm.exe` as it would fail if executed from a bash terminal.

Comment: If you are concerned about portability then you can check `$PSVersionTable.Platform` to see whether the script is being run on Unix or Windows platform and react accordingly.

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell's command-precedence rules are purely based on the command _form_ (alias vs. function vs. cmdlet vs. external program), irrespective of whether a given command _comes with_ PowerShell or Windows. `find` refers to `find.exe`, which is an _external program_, that just so happens to come with Windows. `mkdir` is a _PowerShell function_ that just so happens to come with PowerShell (`mkdir` is _not_ an external program; in the context of `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt) it is an _internal command_, akin to a built-in PowerShell cmdlet).

Comment: if you are working on portable code ... then you need to write portable code. [*grin*] `rm` is not portable code. use something to test the environment you are running in ... and then jump to the code that works for that environment OR call the appropriate file that holds the code for that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Lee Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey)'s helpful comments:

- PowerShell [aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) have *higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Precedence)* than *external programs* with the same (base) name.

  - Note that the precedence rules imply that in the absence of an `rm` alias a (hypothetical) `rm` *function* would take precedence too (and even a *cmdlet*, though the verb-noun naming convention of cmdlets makes this highly unlikely).
  - To see *all* command forms that exist for a given name, use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) with the `-All` switch: `Get-Command rm -All`
  - To *bypass* naming conflicts, invoke the external program *with its filename extension*, namely `rm.exe` in this case; using the program's (full) *path* works too.
- While it is *advisable* for *scripts and modules* to *not* use aliases - to put it differently: it is advisable to use aliases only as an *interactive* convenience - in practice they *do*, so there's a risk of *breaking* code if you remove *built-in* aliases such as `rm`.
- If you're willing to assume this risk, see below for how to remove the `rm` alias; if you want the removal to apply to all future PowerShell sessions too, add the call to your `$PROFILE` file.

---

To remove the `rm` alias, using [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) with the standard `Alias:` drive provided by the [alias provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Alias_Provider):

```
Remove-Item Alias:rm -Force
```

Note:

- In *PowerShell (Core) 6+*, you can more simply use [`Remove-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/remove-alias)  `rm -Force`.
- Not all aliases require `-Force` for removal, but many *built-in* ones do (though not `rm`, specifically).